# How to give a specific name to foreign key?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

For our Mysql database, my modifications in log.orm.yml file will generate this SQL query :

```
ALTER TABLE te_journal_log ADD 
    user_id INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE te_journal_log ADD 
    CONSTRAINT FK_1E6EB7B7A76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
    REFERENCES te_user_usr (id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_1E6EB7B7A76ED395 ON te_journal_log (user_id);
```

It worked perfectly.

BUT ;-) because of ours naming policies, I'm searching how to replace the constraint's name `FK_1E6EB7B7A76ED395` and the index's name `IDX_1E6EB7B7A76ED395` by `fk_log_user` and `i3_log`. I found nothing in the documentation.

I had a look on source code, especially [the 1088th line of AbstractPlatform.php file](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/tree/9ec9bb9bfc7641ba0dc36e32650c0e2fefe79a06/lib/Doctrine/DBAL#L1088) but It doesn't help me to force the name of my foreign key. Could you help me please ?

Alexandre

Modification in the log.orm.yml file :

```
  manyToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
      joinColumns:
        user_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to rename constraints.  You can just drop it and recreate it.  The same for the index:

```
alter table te_journal_log drop constraint FK_1E6EB7B7A76ED395;

alter table te_journal_log 
    add constraint fc_tel_userid foreign key (user_id) references te_user_usr (id);

drop index IDX_1E6EB7B7A76ED395;

create index idx_tel_userid on te_journal_log(user_id);
```

Note:  in the future, you can provide the names you want in the `create table` and `create index` statements.  This is a good reason to write those statements directly in SQL.

Comment: Thank you Gordon ! I think we will drop it and recreate it. Have you got some informations or links about your last note ?

Comment: If you use migrations (you should!) you can first create the migration with the command doctrine:migrations:diff, then edit it to change the name of the FK and then run it with doctrine:migrations:migrate

Comment: I didn't know this Bundle. It's excellent. Thank you Carlos !

Comment: Sorry for delay ! I tried the doctrine migration tools and it works perfectly. It does what I want ! Thank you for your help !